# start-server-and-test stuck at server start - ( Error: Timed out waiting )

Tags: node.js, testing, types, graphql

I was trying to use `start-server-and-test` but I have a graphQL server. I have tried many endpoints but it seems it wont return 200 status henceforth it's not executing the second command.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --files --exec ts-node src/index.ts",
    "test-server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test ts-node --files src/index.ts ",
    "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest",
    "ci": "start-server-and-test test-server https://localhost:4000 test",
    "gen-schema-types": "gql2ts src/schema.graphql -o src/types/schema.d.ts"
}
```

Why is the second command not executing?

Answer (score 1):

Should your localhost url be http instead of https?

```
    "ci": "start-server-and-test test-server http://localhost:4000 test",
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently, resolved by using 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost. I only tried this because the server reads on startup:

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
```

I realize these two typically work the same, so I do not have an explanation for why localhost was not working here.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself. I tried using http-get, and using 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost without success. Using tcp fixed the issue for me.

Try changing your example into:

```
"ci": "start-server-and-test test-server tcp:4000 test"
```